# Join query between two big tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, bigtable

i have to run a join query between Tow big table in mysql every table's size is 300MB , the problem the execution time in mysql , can some one help me ?

Comment: Please add more information, p.e. table & data structures, your current query.

Comment: If you have performance problems, you might need to add indexes. For more help you must show the table structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider to use an external tools:

[Google BigQuery](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/overview)